Pandas Time Series Resampling & handling large gaps
I am struggling to find a good solution to resample pandas time series data to a fixed 5 minute grid while avoiding interpolation between distant data (>1h apart) and marking these as NaN.
To reduce the time alignment error, i want to use interpolation. However, no interpolation should happen when the distance to the next value is greater than one hour and the values in between should be set to NaN.
def resample(series):
    series = series.resample('1s').interpolate(limit=3*60, limit_direction='both').resample('5min').asfreq()

    # Set values between groups >1h apart to NaN 
    time_diff = series.index.to_series().diff().shift(-1)
    mask = time_diff.abs() > timedelta(hours=1)
    mask = mask.reindex(series.index, method='ffill').fillna(False)
    series[mask] = np.nan

    return series

While my current solution kind-of achieves this (first image), the interpolation for singular values is still wrong (second image). This is because values are still being interpolated towards the previous/next value and the masking rule would not work here. Single values would be better handled without interpolation and just mapped to the nearest 5 minute sample.
As an alternative approach I was thinking to perform grouped operations (splitting groups when distance > 1h e.g. by using a cumsum approach on the diff), resample the groups individually and afterwards merge all data into a single series.
Are there other ideas? I keep thinking that this should be a rather common problem and i might just fail to see the right approach.
Just to repeat the goal: I want to resample the un-equally spaced time-series data to a new 5 minute grid and use interpolation (within groups) to minimize the time-alignment error in contrast to just assigning the values to the nearest 5 minute interval.


